# Jekyll detect sass file with yaml front matter as page

Tags: html, css, sass, jekyll, yaml-front-matter

I made a liquid template for navigation menu and tried to add active css rule to current active menu item.

Here are my liquid tag to render the menu item:

```liquid
<ul class="list-inline float-right">
    {% assign menu_pages = site.pages | sort: 'index' %}
    {% for p in menu_pages limit 3 %}
        {% if page.menu_title and page.url == p.url %}
        <li class="active"><a href="{{ p.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ p.menu_title }}</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ p.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ p.menu_title }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

`index` is a yaml front matter variable to sort menu items.
`menu_title` is a yaml front matter variable to add custom menu title shown on the menu bar.

I add those two front matter variables above directly to my `.html` file in root which are going to be rendered as pages.

But when I checked this on browser, I got another blank menu items that link me to my main.css and framework.css file.

Here is the rendered html:

```html
<ul class="list-inline float-right">
    <li><a href="/css/main.css"></a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/framework.css"></a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/works/">Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

This happened right after I include my main.sass and framework.sass file to Jekyll assets which located in `css` folder while the partial sass file in `_sass` folder. I assume the front matter makes those two sass file being rendered as pages and this is because of yaml front matter I added to my two sass file. I tried to delete the double `---` line on top of them then I refresh the localhost and the blank menu items gone.

I have three menu items to be rendered:

- Home
- Works
- Blog

but the result is five!

So is it true that this because the yaml front matter? How can I fix this while using Jekyll sass assets pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you'd be better to use `site.html_pages` instead:

```
{% assign menu_pages = site.html_pages | sort: 'index' %}
```

From https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#site-variables, `site.html_pages` is:

> A subset of `site.pages` listing those which end in `.html`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's going to be a good solution too. Never use this variable before.

Comment: Hey @RossPhillips. It fixed the problem! But I'm still curious why sass file is rendered as a pages? But anyway, my html is now rendered properly. Thanks. :)

Comment: Any file with front matter that isn't a post or collection item seems to go in there, I've encountered the same issue with XML files before. I'm sure there are some good use cases for it.

Comment: So this not only me who has the same problem. Thanks for the explanation 

Answer (score 1):

Your if clause is filtering on menu_title but the else clause is not filtering. You can change your condition to :

```
{% if page.menu_title %}
  <li{% if page.url == p.url %} class="active">{% endif %}
    <a href="{{ p.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ p.menu_title }}</a>
  </li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It helps me simplify the code, thanks! :) But @rossp helps fix the problem. It's about file extension. I should use `site.html_pages` rather than only `site.pages` to avoid my two sass files being rendered on menu link.